# Querying the median time between the second and third edit

Tags: sql

I have the following table;

```
| uuid | user_id | user_created | profile_edited |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|:------:|:------:|
| 1c5d134c  | user_3    | 2022-11-10T19:09:05+00:00 | 2022-11-18T18:00:05+00:00
| 1c5d134b  | user_3    | 2022-11-10T19:09:05+00:00 | 2022-11-15T18:00:05+00:00
| 1c5d134a  | user_3    | 2022-11-10T19:09:05+00:00 | 2022-11-14T18:00:05+00:00
| 1c5d434a  | user_1    | 2022-11-10T19:09:05+00:00 | 2022-11-13T19:09:05+00:00
| 1c8b424b  | user_1    | 2022-11-10T19:09:05+00:00 | 2022-11-10T16:09:05+00:00
| 1c8b424c  | user_2    | 2022-11-01T19:09:05+00:000 | 2022-11-19T19:09:05+00:00
| 1c8b424a  | user_2    | 2022-11-01T19:09:05+00:000 | 2022-11-22T19:09:05+00:00
| 1c8b424b  | user_2    | 2022-11-01T19:09:05+00:000 | 2022-11-24T19:09:05+00:00
| 1c5d434c  | user_1    | 2022-11-10T19:09:05+00:00 | 2022-11-18T19:09:05+00:00
| 1c5d434e  | user_1    | 2022-11-10T19:09:05+00:00 | 2022-11-16T19:09:05+00:00
| 1c5d434c  | user_1    | 2022-11-10T19:09:05+00:00 | 2022-11-14T19:09:05+00:00
```

In the example above we can see the second and third profile edit times as below;

```
| user_id | second_edit | third_edit | difference
|:---- |:------:| -----:|:------:|:------:|
| user_1  | 2022-11-13T19:09:05+00:00 | 2022-11-14T19:09:05+00:00 | 24 hours
| user_2  | 2022-11-22T19:09:05+00:00 | 2022-11-24T19:09:05+00:00 |48 hours
| user_3  | 2022-11-15T18:00:05+00:00 | 2022-11-18T18:00:05+00:00 | 72 hours
```

And the resulting query should find the median between 24, 48, and 72.

Comment: `mysql` <> `postgresql`. I removed these conflicting tags, please tag only the one database that you are running.

Comment: What is the *median* of a timestamp?  Please show us the result that you would like for your sample data (you might also want to simplify those dates to make it easier to follow the logic).

Comment: Updated the question with examples. Thanks! @GMB

Comment: *the resulting query should find the median between 24, 48, and 72* , do you want to return the 48 value only?

Comment: Yes. In this example median would be 48 @ahmed

Comment: What DBMS you are using? MySQL or Postgresql

Comment: It is supposed to be vendor-neutral. @ahmed

Answer (score 0):

In POSTGRES you can do something like this.

first get the row_number for every uuid descending by the date edited,
The rest is getting the difference.

You can use this and derive similar solutions for MySQL

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
"uuid", "user_id", "user_created","profile_edited",
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "uuid" ORDER BY "profile_edited" DESC) rn
FROM TableB)
SELECT
  "uuid",string_agg(DISTINCT "user_id", ','), MAX("user_created")  "user_created",
 AGE((SELECT "profile_edited" FROM CTE WHERE rn = 2 AND "uuid" = CTE."uuid"   LIMIT 1)
  , (SELECT "profile_edited" FROM CTE WHERE rn = 3 AND "uuid" = CTE."uuid"  LIMIT 1)) AS difference
  FROM CTE
GROUP BY "uuid"
```

| uuid | string_agg | user_created | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1c5d434c | user_1 | 2022-11-10 19:09:05 | 2 days |
| 1c8b424a | user_1,user_2 | 2022-11-10 19:09:05 | 2 days |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UTBkQfJj)

To your changed Question

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
 "user_id", "user_created","profile_edited",
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "user_id" ORDER BY "profile_edited" ASC) rn
FROM TableB),
  CTE2 AS(

  SELECT
 "user_id"
  ,MAX("profile_edited") filter (where rn = 2 AND "user_id" = CTE."user_id") "second"
  ,MAX("profile_edited") filter (where rn = 3 AND "user_id" = CTE."user_id") "third",
   abs(extract(epoch from
  MAX("profile_edited") filter (where rn = 2 AND "user_id" = CTE."user_id") -
  MAX("profile_edited") filter (where rn = 3 AND "user_id" = CTE."user_id")
  )/3600)::INTEGER AS difference_hours
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY "user_id")
SELECT * FROM CTE2
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Median',NULL,NULL,AVG(difference_hours)::INTEGER FROM CTE2
```

| user_id | second | third | difference_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_1 | 2022-11-13 19:09:05 | 2022-11-14 19:09:05 | 24 |
| user_2 | 2022-11-22 19:09:05 | 2022-11-24 19:09:05 | 48 |
| user_3 | 2022-11-15 18:00:05 | 2022-11-18 18:00:05 | 72 |
| Median | *null* | *null* | 48 |

> ```
> SELECT 4
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/biNC6jbG)

Answer (score 0):

In postgres you can use the `percentile_cont` ordered-set aggregate function to find the median as the following:

```
with edit_diff as
(
  select round(extract('epoch' from max(profile_edited)-min(profile_edited))/3600) difference
  from
  (
    select *, 
      row_number() over (partition by user_id order by profile_edited) rn
    from table_name
  ) T
  where rn in(2,3)
  group by user_id
)
select percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by difference) median
from edit_diff
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/v2_WPuaM).

OUTPUT: 48

For MySQL you can use `row_number()` and `count` functions to calculate the median as the following:

```
with edit_diff as
(
  select timestampdiff(hour, min(profile_edited), max(profile_edited)) difference
  from
  (
    select *, 
      row_number() over (partition by user_id order by profile_edited) rn
    from table_name
  ) T
  where rn in(2,3)
  group by user_id
)

select round(avg(difference), 2) median
from
(
  select difference,
         row_number() over (order by difference) diffOrder,
        count(*) over () cn
  from edit_diff
) T
where diffOrder between floor((cn + 1) / 2) and ceil((cn + 1) / 2);
```

Comment: You didn't specify which DBMS you are using, so I posted two queries for both.